# Differentiating a piecewise function

Tags: maple

I am trying to differentiate the piecewise function shown in the picture below using Maple
[image]

However when I assign the piecewise function to `H` using the following code

```
H := piecewise(gamma <> 0, exp(-(1 + gamma*(x - alpha)/beta)^(-1/gamma)), gamma = 0, exp(-exp(-(x - alpha)/beta)))
```

the function when γ=0 is being ignored and I am not sure why. I am getting the following output
[image]
As a result, when I try to find the derivative with respect to x, the derivative when γ=0 is omitted. I am kindly seeking assistance on how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name `gamma` is a [predefined constant](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/view.aspx?path=initialconstants) in Maple.

```
evalf(gamma);

        0.5772156649
```

You could first declare is `local` at the top-level, or you could use another name.

For example,

```
restart;
local gamma;

H := piecewise(gamma <> 0,
               exp(-(1 + gamma*(x - alpha)/beta)^(-1/gamma)),
               gamma = 0,
               exp(-exp(-(x - alpha)/beta)));
```

Comment: Thank you very much @acer. I have learnt something very important thanks to you. I always like to use these greek letters a lot when I am doing the coding. So I can say it is safe to declare `local` at the top-level.

Comment: If it serves you as you want, please feel free to  "accept" the Answer.